# serious struct issues C++

Tags: c++

I'm lost, I'm pretty sure this code is 95% wrong and I need help. What I need to do is take a .txt file and separate the words into a type, price and wanted or for sale. It basically works like a craigslist but the requirements are that I count the amount of operations and delete the wanted and for sale out of the struct-array if it finds a match. I am really not sure how to delete the item out of the array after they have been matched and I keep getting an error saying "std::ifstream has no member named "find".

Heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// Maximum amount to read from a line in the file
const int SIZE = 100;  // Size of input array

char input[SIZE];     // To hold file input

struct itemArray
{
    string type;
    int price;
    int status; //for sale =0, wanted = 1
    int length;
};

void findItem(itemArray[i].type, itemArray[i].price)//searches to see if there is a match, if there is it deletes it from the array
{
    for (int x = 0; x < itemArray.length) //will search for everything in the array
    {
        if itemArray[i].type == itemArray[x].type && itemArray[i].price >= itemArray[x].price && itemArray[x].status ==0;) //if the item outside of the function matches in both type and price then sell it
        {

        }
    }
}

// Function prototypes


int main()
{
    int index;
    int length;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("messageBoard.txt"); //opening the file
    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        while (myfile.good())
        {
            getline(myfile, line);

            int indexofcomma = myfile.find(",");

            itemArray[index].type = myfile.substr(0, indexofcomma); //setting the type of item

            string newstr = myfile.substr(indexofcomma+2, myfile.length()-1); //shortening the string to get rest of information


            int newcomma = newstr.find(","); //separate the the word into a item when a comma is detected

            if (newstr.substr(0, newcomma) == "wanted")

                {

                     itemArray[index].forSale = false;  //prints out a 0

                     //findItem(itemArray.type, itemArray.status-1, itemArray.price);

                 } else {

                    itemArray[index].forSale = true; //prints out a 1

                 }

            itemArray[index].price = stoi(newstr.substr(newcomma+2, newstr.length())); //converts string to int and sets price of Item

            index++;

            length++;//keeping track of the length of the array

            cout << itemsArray[10].type << " " << itemsArray[10].price << endl;

        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= itemArray.length; i++)//loop to find every item that is wanted in the list
        {
            if (itemArray[i].status = 1)//if item is wanted
            {
                findItem(itemArray.type[i], itemArray[i].price)//look for a seller with a similar price
            }
        }
    }


    myfile.close;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the .txt I'm using

```
chicken, for sale, 60
microwave, wanted, 201
bike, for sale, 60
bike, wanted, 50
microwave, for sale, 200
chicken, for sale, 25
chicken, wanted, 25
microwave, wanted, 10
microwave, for sale, 2
chicken, for sale, 100
bike, wanted, 100
chicken, for sale, 5
truck, wanted, 1000
bike, for sale, 50
chicken, for sale, 5
bike, for sale, 500
chicken, for sale, 1
chicken, for sale, 25
bike, wanted, 60
truck, wanted, 2000
truck, for sale, 2500
bike, wanted, 100
truck, for sale, 300
bike, for sale, 100
chicken, for sale, 10000
truck, for sale, 2000
truck, wanted, 1000
dresser, for sale, 20
truck, wanted, 9000
truck, wanted, 8000
truck, for sale, 4000
dresser, for sale, 2
dresser, wanted, 800
microwave, wanted, 70
truck, for sale, 2000
truck, for sale, 2000
truck, wanted, 1000
microwave, for sale, 60
dresser, for sale, 2000
dresser, wanted, 60
dresser, wanted, 50
truck, wanted, 1000
truck, for sale, 500
truck, for sale, 1500
dresser, for sale, 100
dresser, wanted, 200
dresser, for sale, 450
truck, for sale, 2000
truck, wanted, 1000
truck, for sale, 500
dresser, for sale, 500
dresser, wanted, 200
chicken, wanted, 5
chicken, for sale, 5
truck, wanted, 1000
chicken, for sale, 1
chicken, for sale, 25
chicken, wanted, 16
truck, wanted, 2000
chicken, for sale, 15
chicken, wanted, 5
chicken, for sale, 2
microwave, wanted, 15
microwave, wanted, 75
microwave, for sale, 65
chicken, for sale, 5
bike, for sale, 50
chicken, for sale, 1
chicken, for sale, 25
bike, for sale, 50
chicken, wanted, 25
microwave, wanted, 10
microwave, for sale, 2
chicken, for sale, 1
chicken, for sale, 25
bike, for sale, 50
chicken, wanted, 25
bike, wanted, 30
chicken, wanted, 16
chicken, for sale, 15
microwave, wanted, 70
microwave, for sale, 60
microwave, wanted, 50
bike, wanted, 75
truck, wanted, 1000
microwave, wanted, 201
microwave, for sale, 200
truck, wanted, 1000
chicken, for sale, 25
chicken, wanted, 25
truck, wanted, 1000
microwave, wanted, 10
bike, for sale, 10
truck, for sale, 2000
microwave, for sale, 2
truck, wanted, 4000
truck, for sale, 2000
microwave, for sale, 2
truck, wanted, 4000
bike, for sale, 100
```

All help is appreciated, call me an idiot or what ever you need but I need the insight.

Comment: You correctly call `getline` to read a line into a string, but then you call `find()` on the *file stream*, not the *string*.  I can't help with the rest of your question, as it's a little too broad.

Comment: `myfile.close` should probably me `myfile.close()` as well...

Comment: Don't you mean `I'm sure this is 95% *right*`?

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Why do you suspect that?

Comment: @Potatoswatter It doesn't sound right in the context.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Maybe it agrees perfectly with the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Single Responsibility Principle

Learn it. Love it. Follow it. Write code where each part has one and only one responsibility.

In this case, I'd start with a struct that does nothing but store one item from the input file:

```
struct item { 
    std::string item;
    std::string action;
    int price;
};
```

Then I'd write a piece of code that just reads one item from a file into a struct:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, item &i) { 
    std::getline(is, i.name, ',');
    std::getline(is, i.action, ',');
    return is >> i.price;
}
```

Then write code to read data from a file into a vector of items:

```
std::ifstream infile("input.txt");

std::vector<item> items {
    std::istream_iterator<item>(infile),
    std::istream_iterator<Item>(),
};
```

From there, it sounds like you want to partition the data into a portion for "wanted" items, and a portion for "for sale" items. Then you'd match up "for sale" items with "wanted items" where the item description is the same, and the selling price is less than or equal to the buying price.

To do that, you'd probably want to start with `std::partition` to separate the for-sale from the wanted items.

Then you'd use `std::sort` to sort each half (probably on name and price).

Finally, you could use `std::set_symmetric_difference` to remove matching wanted/for-sale items.

Comment: `std::sort` will already do the partitioning given an appropriate `operator<`, and `std::set_symmetric_difference` seems to better match the given requirement. Doesn't look like he needs to match unequal prices, given the data.

Comment: You certainly *could* use a single call to `sort`, but for somebody who seems to be struggling just to read data from a file, I'd rather avoid it. I hadn't really considered `set_symmetric_difference`, but rereading, you're right--since he just wants to remove matched items, it's probably the best fit (I was originally thinking of wanting a list of the items that matched, but you're right--he doesn't seem to want that).

Answer (score 0):

Jerry Coffin has outlined the basic idea of requirement-based software development, and provided the first step: Decide how to store your basic data (a "schema," if you like).

Next, you need to find an algorithm that will solve the problem. You've described it in somewhat obtuse mechanical terms, but the purpose of this program seems to be, "match buyers with sellers, and print the listings that couldn't be matched."

Let's tackle this with a list of buyers and a list of sellers. We can broker a deal if the asking price and the selling price are exactly equal. (This isn't particularly realistic, but it seems to be the intent reflected in the example data set.)

If the lists of buyers and sellers are both sorted, we can simply read them in the same order and quickly see who is missing. Think of it like an attendance roll call: it's easy to see who is absent from class, given a list of enrolled students and an alphabetized sign-in sheet. Scanning through the list of [algorithms in the C++ standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), I can find [std::set_symmetric_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) which does this sort of "attendance check."

To sort the data, we need to define a less-than relationship. We'll sort buyers before sellers, so as to treat the two halves of the sorted data as separate lists. This relationship may be called `operator <`, making it an operator overload. Once they're separated, we need a different less-than relationship to define the "alphabetization" of the "attendance check." This one gets a more descriptive name, `item_price_comparison`, since it's ignoring the information about buying/selling. (It will always be used to compare one buyer against one seller.)

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

typedef std::string item_action;
const item_action sell = "for sale";
const item_action buy = "wanted";

struct item {
    item_action action;
    std::string item;
    int price;
};

// Compare such that matching "buy" and "sell" are equal.
// (Neither is less-than the other.)
bool item_price_comparison( item const & lhs, item const & rhs ) {
    return lhs.item < rhs.item? true
        : rhs.item < lhs.item? false
        : lhs.price < rhs.price;
}

// Compare such that sells come before buys.
bool operator < ( item const & lhs, item const & rhs ) {
    return lhs.action < rhs.action? true
         : rhs.action < lhs.action? false
         : lhs.item < rhs.item? true
         : rhs.item < lhs.item? false
         : lhs.price < rhs.price;
}

std::istream & operator >> ( std::istream & s, item & i ) {
    std::getline( s >> std::ws, i.item, ',');
    std::getline( s >> std::ws, i.action, ',');
    s >> i.price;
    return s;
}

std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & s, item const & i ) {
    s << i.item << ", ";
    s << i.action << ", ";
    s << i.price << "\n";
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::ifstream file( "messageBoard.txt" ); // Open the file.
    std::vector< item > items; // Create the "database."
    std::copy( std::istream_iterator< item >( file ), {},
               std::back_inserter( items ) ); // Read the data.

    std::sort( items.begin(), items.end() ); // Organize the data.
    // Split list: items before first_buyer are for sale, after are wanted.
    auto first_buyer = std::lower_bound( items.begin(), items.end(),
                           item{ buy } );

    std::set_symmetric_difference( // Find mismatches between...
        items.begin(), first_buyer, // ... the list of sellers...
        first_buyer, items.end(), // ... and the list of buyers...
        std::ostream_iterator< item >( std::cout ), // and print the results.
        item_price_comparison // Let matching buy and sell be equal.
    );
}
```

A small change will make this program a better broker, by matching a buyer with a seller whose asking price is lower.

```
// Compare such that matching "buy" and "sell" are equal.
// (Neither shall be less-than the other if they have a deal.)
// Assume that we are comparing one buy with one sell.
bool item_price_comparison( item const & lhs, item const & rhs ) {
    item const & buyer = lhs.action == buy? lhs : rhs;
    item const & seller = lhs.action == sell? lhs : rhs;

    return lhs.item < rhs.item? true
        : rhs.item < lhs.item? false
        : seller.price < buyer.price? false // We have a deal.
        : lhs.price < rhs.price; // Usual rule applies if no deal.
}
```

This broker will pick the first buyers, which are the ones with the lowest offers, and leave very high bids in the lurch. You can remedy that problem by sorting greatest-to-least, but that's well beyond the requirements.